# develop iphone application in arabic language

Tags: iphone, arabic

how can i develop an arabic iphone application?it is included in all iphone sdk?and how to use it?
thks

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.  If you wanted to, you would have to convert Obj-c into arabic yourself, using something like `#define arabicphrasehere NSString(or whatever)`

Comment: i will try it ,but i doubt that there is other solutions

Answer (score 1):

The code itself cannot be written with non-english characters, so that basically leaves out development of most non-latin languages.  As for making apps which support arabic, Apple has great support for supporting apps in multiple languages -- its really quite straight forward -- http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html