# using arabic fonts in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am working on an application where I have to display text in Arabic language. Can some one suggest me how will I convert a text in English to Arabic language.

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: possible duplicate of [develop iphone application in arabic language ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158664/develop-iphone-application-in-arabic-language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSString itself works. It accepts arabic words and displays the word.

Answer (score 1):

Using a translate service that has a public API. [Google Translate](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html) for example: